# Insert missing dates into sqlite result set?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table filled with data for given dates. Sometimes I do not have a row for a given day because I might not have data for that day. Now when I query to get the results I would like to have the result set include a row for every date from the earliest date to the latest. Is there a way to form a query that will generate a default row when a date is missing in the results set without actually inserting them in the database? The date column is in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what the data type, you can create a default value for any column in your table. Please read about the [SQL DEFAULT Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp).

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    date TEXT DEFAULT '2012-08-17');
```

Or if you want to return a default value every time you query your database, use [IfNull()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp):

```
SELECT IfNull(date, '2012-08-17') FROM Foo;
```

(I have assumed that your `date` is text, however you can easily change this.)